# Stored procedure to return a specific interval of records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have to make a view in an application for a table that has many hundred thousand records. For obvious reasons, I don't want to retrieve them all at once.

The convention is to make stored procedures to query the database tables, so my plan was to make a stored procedure to return an interval of records (like records 2000 to 3000). I know the trick to use a nested query to retrieve a range of records with `TOP`, but as far as I can tell, you can't parametrize the argument to `TOP`.

This will be used in conjunction with datasets and `DataTable`s in a C# application.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take advantage of ROW_NUMBER in SQL Server 2008. Below query will returns only 10 rows based on row number.

```
WITH Ordered AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderID) AS RowNumber, OrderID, OrderDate
FROM Orders)
SELECT * 
FROM Ordered
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 21 AND 30
```

Answer (score 3):

You *can* parameterize the argument to top. Enclose the argument in (braces).

If you need all of them anyway it is more efficient to just get all of them in one go. No need to chunk.

Comment: I won't necessarily need them all. I'd be surprised that anyone is interested in more than the few top rows, but I still have to support the functionality. I'll get back a thousand or so at a time.

Comment: you can page with CTE like [here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/03/30/More-SQL-Server-2005-Solutions.aspx)